# R replacing NaN with 0 using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

My dataframe looks like this -

```
dataset = data.frame(ID=c(1:3),Count=c(22,NaN,13))
```

I'm trying to use the pipe operator to replace NaN with 0

```
dataset = dataset %>% replace('NaN',0)
```

However this doesn't work.
I've looked at the solutions on this websites, but none seem to work.

Any inputs would be highly appreciated.

Comment: `dataset %>% mutate_at(vars(Count), ~replace(., is.nan(.), 0))`

Comment: `dataset[is.na(dataset)] <- 0` - no need for dplyr.

Comment: @DanM I added few more targets where `NaN` values are converted to 0. Should be fine now?

Comment: I dont think this question is a duplicate of the first and of the second links, because NAs are different from NaNs in R. For the third and fourth link, it might be a duplicate, but a specific package was asked in this question `dplyr`. However, NaNs are most often produced as a result of implossible calculations as 0/0 and sqrt or log of negative numbers. So probably best way to remove NaNs is by correcting the code before it is produced.

Comment: @jay.sf For this simple example, that works, but in general this will not work for a solution requiring the pipe operator like the OP wants.

Comment: `mutate_at` has been superseded. An updated version of @RonakShah's answer is: `dataset %>% mutate(across(Count, ~ replace(., is.nan(.), 0)))`.

Comment: `dataset |> mutate(across(everything(), ~replace_na(., 0)))`

Answer (score 5):

This'll do it, and doesn't even require dplyr as it's in base:

```
dataset$Count[is.nan(dataset$Count)]<-0
```

Comment: I tired to do this, but I am getting an error saying `Error in is.nan(df) : 
  default method not implemented for type list`. Do you know what the issue is or how to solve it?

Comment: We'd have to look at your data to be sure, but I note you're naming a whole dataframe, not a variable in it. (note the example references dataset$Count, not just dataset).  is.nan specifically refers to numeric variables (hence "nan" rather than "na") and therefore can't be applied to non-numeric variables.  From a quick Google I'm guessing either that (df) is a variable or list rather than a dataframe, or else there is a non-numeric variable in the dataframe (df).